# Obter trecho de um String com expressão regular

Tags: java

No código há uma  string que contém HTML. Dentro desse HTML há um `embed` de um vídeo do YouTube:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZJLAJVmggt0%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0%26ap=%2526fmt=18" width="725" height="400"></embed>
```

Preciso obter desse trecho apenas o ID do vídeo do YouTube, que no caso acima seria o `ZJLAJVmggt0`.

Como fazer isso sabendo que a string está dentro de uma iteração, ou seja, a cada ciclo a variável muda de valor, por tanto o trecho acima nunca está na mesma posição dentro da string e o ID do vídeo é diferente a cada iteração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex) no SOen:

Utilizando a [expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240215/6630) `.*youtube.com/./(.*?)%.*` com o `Matcher`:

Exemplo:

```
String mydata = "<STRING_COM_O_CODIGO_EMBED_DO_YOUTUBE>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*youtube.com/./(.*?)%.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = .... ;
var id = t.replace(/.*youtube.com\/.\/(.*?)%.*/, '$1');
console.log(id);
```

EDIT: Ooops: wrong Java...

```
String id = t.replaceAll(".*youtube.com/./(.*?)%.*","$1")
```

Comment: @Articuno, Ooops, li mal... (daqui a um bocado vou remover a resposta)

Comment: Não funciona, entretanto consegui resolver utilizando a expressão regular da sua resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes, Que tipo de erro obtens? Qual é a tua versão de java? (eu testei con sucesso com java 1.8.0_45) , a string "t" contem mais que uma linha?

Comment: O código não extrai o ID do Youtube como informei na pergunta. Eu quero obter o ID do video e não removê-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o código abaixo fará o que você precisa:

```
String mydata = "<embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/ZJLAJVmggt0%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0%26ap=%2526fmt=18\" width=\"725\" height=\"400\"></embed>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=youtube.com/v/)(.*?)(?=\\%)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Input:**

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZJLAJVmggt0%26hl=en%26fs=1%26rel=0%26ap=%2526fmt=18" width="725" height="400"></embed>
```

**REGEX:**

```
(?<=youtube.com/v/)(.*?)(?=\%)
```

**Output:**

```
ZJLAJVmggt0
```